# MATLAB crops EPSs of `surf` and `plot` differently

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, eps

Usually, when I print a figure to an EPS file, it crops out the blank spaces, e.g.,

```
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(1:10,1:10)
print -depsc 'plot_fig'
```

The EPS file includes *only* the plotted part. The same happens when I use `imagesc` or `contour`. However, when I do the same routine with the `surf` command, MATLAB does not crop out the blank spaces. Try this:

```
[xgrid,ygrid] = ndgrid(-1:0.01:1,-1:0.01:1);
xplot= -1:0.01:1;
func = @(x,y) x+y
subplot(2,2,1)
surf(xplot,xplot,func(xgrid,ygrid))
print -depsc 'surf_fig'
```

Here, the blank three-quarters of the figure are included in the EPS file. Why is this happening? How can I reproduce the first functionality with the `surf` command?

Comment: In my case, it didn't crop the blank 3 quarters while saving the `plot` output. What version of Matlab are you using? Mine is R2017a.

Comment: One thing to look for: Is the ‘renderer’ property of these two figure windows the same? (Check with `get(gcf,'renderer')`.)

Comment: Possible solutions would be to crop the generated EPS (not ideal), use `exportfig` from the File Exchange, or use `-loose` option to `print` to force non-crop behavior (not ideal either).

Comment: [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) is a must.

Comment: @Nakini , 2017b, but I had the same behavior with 2013b as well.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Both are `opengl`. The `-loose` option didn't change anything. Just to be sure, I want the 3/4 cropped out (as in 'plot',) when using the  'surf'.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Why? what is export_fig?

Comment: export_fig is a File Exchange submission that we've used for literally a decade because Matlab's figure export is so unreliable. I know it's hard to accept that you'd need a custom package for something so straightforward but after seeing the need for export_fig for so many years and so many places, I just use it every time. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig